# how to get headers from response FetchBlob

Tags: react-native

I am using the react-native fetch-blob library for fetching files into an application. Here is the implemented code:

```
RNFetchBlob.config(platformConfig).fetch('GET', url).then((res) => { 

console.log('---->', res)

 if (Platform.OS=='android') {
            return `file://${res.path()}`;
        } else {
            return res.path();
});
```

Here is the response :
[image]

And here are the headers from the response in Chrome Developers tools
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The response headers are on the response info object

```
res.info().headers
```

from: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/Classes#user-content-rnfetchblobresponseinfo

Comment: thanks for the reply, i already tried this but it shows undefined